# Delete Values from a database using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, database

I have remove which is given as a link. If I click remove I want to remove a value from the database, but certainly its not working... what's wrong?

```
<td align="center">
<div id="remove">
<a href='#' onclick="removeDesign()">remove</a>
</div>
</td>
```

```
function removeDesign()
{
var confirmation = confirm("Are You Sure You Want to Delete This Item?")
if(confirmation == true)
{
  $.post('remove.php',{designId : [<?=$_SESSION['designid']?>]});
}
}
```

remove.php:

```
<?php

include("config/dbconn.php");
$DesignId=$_POST['designId'];
$sql = "delete from design where id = '".$DesignId."'";
mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

The problem is the designid value is not passing to the remove.php? Can any one show the solution?

Comment: Your code screams of a [SQL Injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Right now, it's a good thing that this doesn't work, because it's an enormous SQL injection hole. Imagine if someone submitted `' OR '' = '` as `designId` -- all the records in your database would be gone. Sanitise the data, and look into using prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$.post("remove.php",{designId : "'" +  <?php echo $_SESSION['designid']?> + "'"} );
```

Comment: and make sure php sort tag is enabled